# How to get the first and last numbers in a sequence

Tags: vba, sequence

I'm working with VBA to try and get the first and last numbers in a delimited numerical sequence.

Data is presented as a comma delimited sequence of numbers only.  They are always in numerical ascending order.

So an example of this might be:

`1,2,3,5,7,8,9`

What is required is the first and last of the sequences only, with a sequence defined as being numbers that are one more than the previous number, in this case there are two sequences:
`1,2,3` and `7,8,9`.  5 is not in the sequence since it it separated by more than one before and after it (4 and 6 are missing).

In these two cases, I need the first and last numbers of each sequence ie `1 & 3` for the first sequence and `7 & 9` for the second sequence.

I wonder whether regex would lend itself to this or whether it would be better to put them in to some collection to be able to navigate backwards and forwards more easily?

Not sure where to start really - any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach may be to use `Split`:

```
NumberSequence = "1,2,3,5,7,8,9"
ValueList = Split(NumberSequence, ",")
```

Then pull the values of the first and last index in the ValueList array.

The complication in your problem description is to recognize when there are "missing" numbers in the number sequence, but `Split` will help solve this issue too. After reading the numbers into an array it is easy enough to loop through them and determine where the "gaps" are.

This illustrates the method:

```
Sub SampleProject()
    
    GetMinAndMax "1,2,3,5,7,8,9"

End Sub

Sub GetMinAndMax(NumberSequence As String)
    
    ValueList = Split(NumberSequence, ",")
    
    MinValue = CInt(ValueList(0))
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(ValueList)
        If CInt(ValueList(i)) > CInt(ValueList(i - 1)) + 1 Then
            MaxValue = CInt(ValueList(i - 1))
            
            'Ignore single numbers ("5" in your example)
            If Not MinValue = MaxValue Then MsgBox MinValue & " - " & MaxValue
            
            MinValue = CInt(ValueList(i))
            
        ElseIf i = UBound(ValueList) Then
            MaxValue = CInt(ValueList(UBound(ValueList)))
            MsgBox MinValue & " - " & MaxValue
            
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: whilst `split` will get everything in to an array it doesn't filter out the 5 as this is not sequential since there is no `4` and `6` in the list.

Comment: Per the problem description in the original question, the sequences `1,2,3` and `7,8,9` need to be processed separately. So the answer is to apply `Split` to each of them separately. There is no issue of "filtering out" numbers that do not fall within the sequences you are studying.

Comment: I reread your question and realized what I was missing. You need the code to identify the "breaks" in the sequence as part of the process. Using `Split` is still the easiest way to the goal, but it needs to be elaborated with some logic to identify the breaks. I have expanded my answer above to show one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next function, please:

```
Function SequenceMargins(s As String) As Variant
  Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, strSeq As String, firstEl As Long
  Dim arrFin As Variant, k As Long
  
  arr = Split(s, ",")
  ReDim arrFin(UBound(arr))

  For i = 0 To UBound(arr) - 1
    If CLng(arr(i)) = CLng(arr(i + 1)) - 1 And firstEl = 0 Then firstEl = CLng(arr(i))
    If firstEl <> 0 And CLng(arr(i)) > firstEl And CLng(arr(i)) <> CLng(arr(i + 1)) - 1 Then
        arrFin(k) = firstEl & "&" & arr(i): k = k + 1
        firstEl = 0
    End If
    If i = UBound(arr) - 1 And firstEl <> 0 Then
        arrFin(k) = firstEl & "&" & arr(UBound(arr)): k = k + 1
    End If
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve arrFin(k - 1)
  SequenceMargins = arrFin
End Function
```

It can be called in this way:

```
Sub testSequenceMargins()
  Dim s As String, arr As Variant
  s = "1,2,3,5,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,20,34,35,36"
  arr = SequenceMargins(s)
  Debug.Print UBound(arr), arr(0), arr(UBound(arr))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This method takes an array containing numerical sequences and returns a collection containing the first and last number of every sequence found:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim c As Collection
   Set c = FirstAndLast(Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9))
End Sub

Public Function FirstAndLast(ByVal Sequence As Variant) As Collection
   Dim i As Integer
   
   Set FirstAndLast = New Collection
   
   For i = LBound(Sequence) To UBound(Sequence) - 1
      If Sequence(i) + 1 = Sequence(i + 1) Then
         If FirstAndLast.Count Mod 2 = 0 Then FirstAndLast.Add Sequence(i)
         If i = UBound(Sequence) - 1 Then FirstAndLast.Add Sequence(i + 1)
      Else
         If FirstAndLast.Count Mod 2 = 1 Then FirstAndLast.Add Sequence(i)
      End If
   Next
End Function
```