# How to exctract first and last numbers in a sequence

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sequence

i foung similiar topic, but i can t apply completily that solution to my needs... I want to upgrade excel workbook at my job by making it more auto-entry capable.
Mostly i use excel functions, but sometimes i need some VBA coding, which im not very familiar with. So my problem is, that i need something like this mentioned on this thread. [How to get the first and last numbers in a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62941656/how-to-get-the-first-and-last-numbers-in-a-sequence)
I have box numbers in different sequince in ascening order starting from "A4" to X on
Sheet1. Example Box numbers:   **M004935149,M004935150,M004935151,M004935202,M004935203,M004935204,M004935205**, is it possible when i copy&paste(values) to sheet2 from "A4" to X (depenting on number of boxes copied) to make a string, sentence or whatever is called in specific form in some other cells. **M004935149-151   //   M004935202-205**. I used code from topic in link above, it can make  half job done but i can t figure it out how to make entry from desired cell range and display them on worksheet, and to display values in desired format. Link of screen shoots from my example is following:

[image]

I hope that  someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
Option Explicit
Sub test2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr() As String, result As String, letter As String, cellValue As String, tempLastElement As String
    Dim lastColumn As Long, counter As Long
    Dim firstColumn As Integer, targetRow As Integer, i As Integer
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    firstColumn = 1 'number of first column with target data
    targetRow = 1 'number of row with target data
    
    lastColumn = ws.Range(ws.Cells(targetRow, firstColumn), ws.Cells(targetRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Columns).Count
    ReDim arr(1 To lastColumn - firstColumn + 1)
    letter = Left(ws.Cells(targetRow, firstColumn).Value, 1) 'if count of character in start of string will be more 1, replace 1 on to count of characters
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        cellValue = ws.Cells(targetRow, i).Value
        arr(i) = Right(cellValue, Len(cellValue) - 1) 'if count of character in start of string will be more 1, replace 1 on to count of characters
    Next i
    
    ReDim sequenceArr(1 To UBound(arr))
    sequenceArr(1) = arr(1)
    counter = 2
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) - 1
        If CLng(arr(i)) + 1 = CLng(arr(i + 1)) Then
            tempLastElement = arr(i + 1)
            sequenceArr(counter) = tempLastElement
        Else
            counter = counter + 1
            sequenceArr(counter) = arr(i + 1)
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
        
    Next
    ReDim Preserve sequenceArr(1 To counter)
    result = ""
    counter = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(sequenceArr) - 1
        If counter > UBound(sequenceArr) Then Exit For
        If result = "" Then
            result = letter & sequenceArr(counter) & "-" & Right(sequenceArr(counter + 1), 3)
            counter = counter + 2
        Else
            result = result & "//" & letter & sequenceArr(counter) & "-" & Right(sequenceArr(counter + 1), 3)
            counter = counter + 2
        End If
    Next
    ws.Range("D4").Value = result
End Sub
```

Result on  [image: screenshot]

Comment: I am amazed. Great job. Im not being ungrathefull, but there is a small problem, it work only up to 2 (two) sequience. Can it be changed to make X number of sequince (required when i need to transfer bigger amount of boxes... Or at least 10 diferent sequince?

Comment: @MirkoStanisic It is possible, but there is not enough information to solve this problem. I need more input data with examples of what we need to get in the end. To clarify the bit depth, are we talking about hundreds or thousands from the end? What is the boundary between the last digits? 198,199-200,201 or 161, 162-200, 201. Is there always one letter at the beginning? What to do with the range 299-300? A lot of subtleties

Comment: Oh, okay.  I will explain it.  There is always M the starting letter,  in most cases i need to deliver up to 20 boxes per order, there are usually 2-3 sequience, but sometimes (rare cases) i need to deliver up to 100 boxes and there are 5-10 sequinces in box numbers. My goal is when i copy/paste all oredered boxes i get output format as mentioned. For example, case with more then 2 sequinces format: M004935149-151//M004935202-205//M004936100-130//M004936200-210 etc... So, starting number of sequince "dash" ending number of sequince " every time new sequince is found must be separated with //

Comment: @MirkoStanisic i update code, check it. Now it has become more versatile

Comment: I don t know that to say, you nailed it. Now i can continue my upgrade as planed. God bless you.  One more question, can u please coment this code, so that i can make some modifications if needed, just in case box number change it format?

Comment: @MirkoStanisic i added some comment, if count of characters will be changed.

Comment: Hello, i don t know other way to contac you but i have little problem with code u made for me couple monts ago. Hope u can help me solve that problem? I get error message "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" i posted a question on forum. Can u please read it on this  [link] ?(https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/code-fails-when-generating-sequence-run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range.1186642/)